# ¿Cómo implementar oshi en un proyecto de Java en Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Estoy intentando crear un programa en java mediante Eclipse, el cual pueda obtener información de la PC tal como el modelo del procesador, capacidad del disco duro, versión del S.O., etc.

Estuve investigando y las dos librerías más populares para recopilar esta información son Sigar y Oshi.

Intenté implementar ambas, primero con Sigar no tuve éxito porque parece que cuenta con un problema de compatibilidad con las versiones más recientes de windows.

Opté por intentar implementar oshi pero no logro que funcione en java con eclipse.

Lo primero de todo, en mi proyecto incluí una dependencia de este link (oshi-core-java11-6.3.1.jar):
https://github.com/oshi/oshi

Lo que quiero ejecutar es esto:

```
package cpu;

import oshi.SystemInfo;
import oshi.hardware.CentralProcessor;
import oshi.hardware.HardwareAbstractionLayer;


public class ProcessorInfoExample1 {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        SystemInfo systemInfo = new SystemInfo();
        HardwareAbstractionLayer hardware = systemInfo.getHardware();
        CentralProcessor processor = hardware.getProcessor();

        System.out.println(processor.toString());
    }
}
```

Intenté correrlo pero recibo lo siguiente en consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De mucha documentación he notado que mucha de la configuración se muestra en xml, lo cual desconozco su forma de implementarse en un proyecto de java (creo que está relacionado con Maven o algo así).

Me gustaría que me pudieran indicar qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal aquí o darme una guía mas clara de qué dependencias se deben incluir en el proyecto.

Comment: No olvides mostrar también los mensajes de error _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Por cierto, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Oshi utiliza una librería llamada slf4j para gestionar los logs. Necesitas tenerla en tu proyecto, eso es lo que te está diciendo el error.

Answer (score 2):

Muchas de las librerías disponibles para Java tienen a su vez dependencias de otras librerías, con lo que lo mejor que puedes hacer es usar una herramienta para gestionar las dependencias. Las dos más populares para Java son [Maven](https://javadesde0.com/guia-basica-maven/) y [Gradle](https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2013/12/04/gradle-install/).

Eclipse te permite crear un proyecto como *Maven/Gradle project*, generando las carpetas necesarias e incluyendo el fichero de configuración en la raíz (llamado `pom.xml`, en el caso de Maven, `build.gradle` en el caso de Gradle).

Añade la dependencia ahí y Maven se encargará durante la compilación de gestionar las dependencias, descargando por ti de manera transitiva todas las necesarias.

**Nota**: La mejor documentación siempre será la oficial, pero he añadido dos enlaces a manuales básicos en español para poder tener una primera impresión de un uso básico de ambas herramientas.